# Tomcat ignores application.properties of Spring Boot war application deployed in standalone server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am encountering some problems, while trying to deploy a spring boot application (Spring Boot v 
1.1.6), as a war, in a standalone tomcat (v 7.0.50).

I followed the tutorial http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ (btw, I use Maven).

So, to resume, I put the scope of spring-boot-starter-tomcat to provided and also created a 'web initializer' which extends SpringBootServletInitializer, just like in the example at the link above.

The problem that I have is that it seems Tomcat ignores the application.properties file, as it throws the exception below, when trying to deploy the war:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'myservice.uri' in string value "${myservice.uri}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)

The application.properties file is under src/main/resources. When I run the application using the embedded Tomcat, everything works fine.

It's the second time I convert a jar application to war, using Spring Boot, but the first time I didn't have these issues and I cannot figure out what's the difference between the two (from a configuration point of view).

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to perform a clean-compile-package?

Comment: Yes, I have, but the issue it still the same :(

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier, but if I create a Tomcat instance in Eclipse and deploy my application on that instance, the deployment is successful. But when I copy and paste my war in the webapps folder of Tomcat and then start the server, the deployment fails.

Comment: Have you compared the wars in the two cases?

Comment: My problem is fixed. In my Tomcat configuration the spring active profile was referring to one that had no corresponding properties file, so now the error makes sense.

Comment: Where does that Tomcat configuration for setting the active profile go?